# PHP: preg_match function not working?

Tags: php

I have file type

```
$file_type = image/png 

if (!preg_match("/jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|gif|GIF/", $file_type)) {
     die('Apologies, file type error');
}
```

If the file type is not matching in given pattern it gives dies as shown above. Now I face no matching even the file type is is included in pattern.

The button line is if the file type is not correct I need to die else continue.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://regex101.com/r/CI5ja3/1

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$file_type = "image/png"; 

if (!preg_match("#image/(?:png|jpg|webp|gif)#io", $file_type)) {
    die('Apologies, file type error');
}
//if match file_type continue,
```